# Not able to click on links which are hidden until the moused over? How to do that with Selenium 2.0 in Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open a link which is actually hidden until not hovered the mouse over there. How can we actually do that with Selenium Webdriver in Java?

```
WebElement link_Home = driver.findElement(By.name("Appliances")); 
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(link_Home).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Window Ac"))).click().perform();
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Sounds like a cruel joke, a "Close this popup" link that disappears when you mouseover it.

Comment: WebElement link_Home = driver.findElement(By.name("Appliances")); 
   Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
   builder.moveToElement(link_Home).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Window Ac"))).click().perform();                               what is wrong in this code?

Comment: Nothing seems to wrong in your code. It is better to understand your problem if you can share the HTML code of your page also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement link_Home = driver.findElement(By.name("Appliances"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(link_Home).build().perform();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("W‌​indow Ac")).click();
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (0, 0): http://www.snapdeal.com/products/mobiles  this is coming   ;

Comment: Okay, It's better to update your question with the test url & the scenario you want to achieve. So that more members can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi  i found a nice way to do so

```
WebElement moveonmenu = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='navlink ']")).get(4);
         Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
         actions.moveToElement(moveonmenu).build().perform();
         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); //here, wait time is 20 seconds
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(moveonmenu));
        List <WebElement> moveonmenu1=driver.findElements(By.className("subnavCont")).get(4).findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        for (int i = 0; i < moveonmenu1.size(); i++) {
            if( moveonmenu1.get(i).getAttribute("text").toString().equals("title"))
             {
                 System.out.println("coming here");
                 moveonmenu1.get(i).click();
                 break;
             }
```